# Remove one part of url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've had my page structure like this for a while: https://www.(DOMAIN).(TLD)/page/(SLUG)
Now I want to change it to: https://www.(DOMAIN).(TLD)/(SLUG)

How can I do this best?

This is what I already have:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Include "www" and change "http" to "https".
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Ignore some stuff.
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# The page part.
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_\-]+)$ index.php?mode=page&slug=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_\-]+)/$ index.php?mode=page&slug=$1 [NC,L]

# Redirect /page/SLUG to /SLUG?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below condition and rule,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_\-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=page&slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This doesnt redirect the request if request scheme is https.